# Run SQL Scripts post SQL Server and Database Creation

Tags: terraform

I need to run a SQL script to create a user once Terraform has created the Azure SQL Server and a database inside it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your Terraform code?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the `local-exec` provisioner for this sort of task. Here is a quick example:

```
resource "my_db" "db" {

  [...]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = path.module

    command = "./scripts/my_db_script.sh --option=${var.some_db_input}"

    interpreter = ["bash"]
  }
}
```

If your script depends on some variable that is dynamically generated from the DB output (such as IP or FQDN), you might have to combine `local-exec` with `null_resource`.